# removing element from 2d list - false error - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

So I'm trying to swap out a '0' for an 'x' in a grid below but when I try removing the '0', I get an error saying that it is not in the list..

```
grid = [['0','x','x','x'],
        ['x','x','x','x'],
        ['x','x','x','x'],
        ['x','x','x','x'],
        ['x','x','x','x'],
        ['x','x','x','x']]
```

When I try to remove the '0' from the list using this block of code:

```
for x in range(6):
    grid[x].remove('0')

#(I Know That It's Inefficient)
```

I get this error:

```
grid[x].remove('0')
    ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

I don't know whether it is worth noting but I have received this error after trying many different ways, for example:

```
grid.remove('0')
#using no loops

i = grid[x].index('0')
del grid[x][i]
#using the same for loop

i = grid.index('0')
del grid[i]
#in the for loop
```

I received the same error for all of these attempts and I have rewritten the '0' in my 2D array multiple times, could anyone help me to do this simple task?

~THANK YOU~

Comment: Well there are rows in your grid where `0` is not an element. What is not clear about that?

Comment: `remove(x)` is not the same as `remove('0')`

Answer (score 0):

Your program is looping for *each* row and attempting to remove `'0'`. This is successful the first time, but throws a `ValueError` after that. Note how the following program prints 'removed!' once:

```
>>> for x in range(6):
...     grid[x].remove('0')
...     print('removed!')
...
removed!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

There are many ways to remove all `'0'` values from your grid. Here's one way using a list comprehension:

```
>>> [[i for i in row if i != '0'] for row in grid]
[['x', 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x']]
```

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful

Answer (score 0):

The error message is confusing in this case because it uses the variable `x`, which isn't related to your `'x'` strings. From the python docs:

> list.remove(x):
>   Remove the first item from the list whose value is x. **It is an error if there is no such item.**

Your loop tries to remove a '0' from every row of the grid, but some rows don't have a '0', so `remove` throws an error.